# Data compression in Scala

Tags: scala

Here below is my attempt to implement a class that provides functionality for compressing/decompressing strings:

```
object GZipHelper {

  def deflate(txt: String): Try[String] = {
    try {
      val arrOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
      val zipOutputStream = new GZIPOutputStream(arrOutputStream)
      zipOutputStream.write(txt.getBytes)
      new Success(Base64.encodeBase64String(arrOutputStream.toByteArray))
    } catch {
      case _: e => new Failure(e)
    }
  }

  def inflate(deflatedTxt: String): Try[String] = {
    try {
      val bytes = Base64.decodedBase64(deflatedTxt)
      val zipInputStream = GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes))
      new success(IOUtils.toString(zipInputStream))
    } catch {
      case _: e => new Failure(e)
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, the `finally` blocks that close `GZIPOutputStream` and `GZIPInputStream` are missing... how could I implement this in the ''scala'' way? How could I improve the code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're using the "old fashioned" `try` statement and explicitly turning it into a `scala.util.Try`, there really is no reason not to add a `finally` block after your `try`.

In this specific case though, there is little point in closing, for example, your `ByteArrayInputStream` - it's not really an open resource and does not need to be closed. In which case you can simplify your code and make it much more idiomatic this way:

```
def inflate(deflatedTxt: String): Try[String] = Try {
   val bytes = Base64.decodedBase64(deflatedTxt)
   val zipInputStream = GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes))
   IOUtils.toString(zipInputStream)
}
```

I personally would not declare `bytes` and `zipInputStream` since they're only used once, but that's a matter of preference.

The trick here is having a `finally` block with a call to `scala.util.Try.apply` - I'm not sure that's possible without going through a call to `map` that doesn't actually modify anything, which seems like a bit of an oversight to me. I was expecting to see an `andThen` or `eventually` method in `scala.util.Try`, but it doesn't seem to be there (yet?).

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for... the "new fashioned" Try ;-) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6):

Just for completeness, here is the deflate method converted (original version was also missing the close() call on the GZIP class):

```
def deflate(txt: String): Try[String] = Try {
    val arrOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val zipOutputStream = new GZIPOutputStream(arrOutputStream)
    zipOutputStream.write(txt.getBytes)
    zipOutputStream.close()
    Base64.encodeBase64String(arrOutputStream.toByteArray)
}
```

Comment: You could use `java.util.Base64` from Java 8 standard library: `Base64.getEncoder.encodeToString(arrOutputStream.toByteArray)`

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/jsuereth/scala-arm/wiki/basic-usage

this looks like a good approach

Answer (score 0):

You can use scala-compress `https://github.com/gekomad/scala-compress`

compress string:

```
val aString: String = "foo"
val compressed: Try[Array[Byte]] = zipString(aString, charSetName = "UTF-8")
```

decompress:

```
val compressedArray: Array[Byte] = ???
val decompressed: Try[Array[Byte]] = unzipString(compressedArray)  
new String(decompressed, "UTF-8")
```